# Connection between two point layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

I have two point layers: warehouses and shops. They have relation like many to many (one warehouse delivers to several shops and one shop connected with several warehouses). I have ID of that connection. I need to show by filter all warehouses, that delivers to one shop or all shops, that connected with warehouse. Now i have a composition of all objects in two layers and using grouping filter in arcgis portal webappbuilder. Is any method to relate two layers for using in group filter without composition? I need to show feature geometry with label, not only table. I'm trying to build relation class, it works fine in desktop, but after publishing on portal there is no related table in map viewer.